# Multiple conditions in where (pl/sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

i have these table_1:

```
A  |B |C |D
19 |  |  | 
238|  |1 |AS 
45 |23|  | 
196|  |  |
```

I need to delete records with fields B , C and D empty.

Is it ok?

```
Delete From table_1 Where C is null and B is null and D is null;
```

But if I have another table with multiple fields: A,B,C,D,E,F....Z,AA,AB.....BA...

What would be the best way in this case?

Comment: The best case? Make a procedure that loop over all the columns and checks if they are nulls. Also consider checking for empty strings if that case is possible. In general, your query is fine.

Comment: I think that there is a best way to do this:
Delete From table_1 Where C is null and B is null and D is null and E is null and F is null......................;

Comment: Define best way. Best way for what? Daily process? A one time deletion?

Comment: I want to spend all conditions in one. I think that there are a lot of conditions.... and I want a short query

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I thought that you can pass a parameter or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [COALESCE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php):

```
Delete From table_1 
  Where COALESCE(A,B,C,D,E,F,....,Z,AA,AB,.....,BA) is null;
```

Comment: Sorry. ButError SQL: ORA-00932 
: Inconsistent data types : CHAR expected was obtained NUMBER

Comment: @ANOUK_prog   if fields have different types (char,int,...) try to group fields with the same type to different coalesces. `COALESCE(intField1,intfield2,....) IS NULL AND COALESCE(CHARField1,CHARfield2,....) IS NULL `